# Conditional probabilities in a bipartite network

Tags: probability, bipartite-graphs

I have a bipartite network so that each node from one set has to pass through the nodes in the other set before returning to any node in the same set, [Google](http://www.shizukalab.com/_/rsrc/1468739661946/toolkits/sna/bipartite/bipartiteexample1.png?height=169&width=320) example image. If we call the first set G and the other set H, is it always true that

$$
P(G_j | G_i ) = \sum_k ( P(G_j | H_k ) * P(H_k | G_i ) ) ?
$$

Comment: Please format your links using [these instructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Okay updated with a better link